# What is the function of the tag <Container>?

Tags: javascript, html, tags, containers

I was reading a sample code, and I don't understand what the tag  `<Container>`
does here.

```
<Container maxWidth="lg">
  <AppBar className={classes.appBar} position="static" color="inherit">
    <Typography className={classes.heading} variant="h2" align="center">Memories</Typography>
    <img className={classes.image} src={memories} alt="icon" height="60" />
  </AppBar>
  <Grow in>
<Container>
^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I looked it up, and results are all about contianer tags in HTML and functions in js, which doesn't include a tag that looks like `<Container>`. It seems that I can't either search the word `<Container>` , google search just ignores the symbols `<>`. I don't know how to counter that.

Comment: That's not plain HTML

Comment: Are these React components?  It sounds like you're looking at code without knowing what technology uses it, which is definitely going to hinder your searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, it turned out it is a component in material-ui.

Here is the documentation:https://mui.com/components/container/

> The container centers your content horizontally. It's the most basic
> layout element.